# RTSP camera is crashing after 5 seconds of detecting face?

Tags: python, opencv

I am having an issue with this code. When i run this code in jupyter notebook it runs and gets crashes after 10 seconds of detecting face and eyes through rtsp camera. I'm trying to figure out the problem but no luck. Can anyone help me out fixing this?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:\\opencv\\build\\etc\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:\\opencv\\build\\etc\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_eye.xml')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp url')
while (cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    face = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

    for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(gray, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (127,0,255), 2)
        rol_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]

        eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
        for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
            cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0), 2)

        cv2.imshow('Face Detection', frame)

    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff ==ord('q')
    if k == 27:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.waitKey(1)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


This is what i get after crashing 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-dc3a85ff092b> in <module>
     16 while (cap.isOpened()):
     17     ret, frame = cap.read()
---> 18     gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
     19     face = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
     20 

error: OpenCV(4.1.1) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your camera is unable to capture the frame (maybe network issue) and that is the cause of the crash. Add check if the frame was acquired successfully:

```
while (cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == False:
        print("error")
    else:
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        #rest of your code
```

Comment: Piotr Seems like network  issue.  I added check and confirmed it was network issue. Thanks for replying tho